# What is the type of electric motor that can lift 1.6 kg just like micro servos, but without the reduction gear?

Tags: motor, servomotor, torque, movement

Micro servo motors, normally the 9g type can lift 1,6kg with a reduction box made of nylon.

However, I'm interested on lifting this amount of weight (1,6 kg) in a faster rate in the axis of rotation (no mechanical levers).

I tried to see what kind of DC electric motor fits in this specification so I can project what kind of setup I will need, but for some reason google just don't stop showing shopping ads about super heavy duty induction motors.

Comment: @jsotola edited the question, I hope it is better now...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the ways to calculate power is torque times speed. For a given mechanical power, you *must* reduce the speed to increase the output torque.

When you say you want to keep the motor the same, keep the torque the same, and increase the speed, that's not possible.

Ultimately what you're really wanting is a shopping question - you're asking us to find a product that meets your needs - but I wanted to give this answer to point out what you're asking for is not going to exist.